# PCman filemanager displays old data on USB mounted drive

Tags: usb, drive, pcmanfm

When I plug in usb flash drive, or even my camera and open File Manager only old data that was previously on usb drive (or Camera's memory card) is shown. I can't open any of those files or see any new listed. Is there any way to clear usb cache, some temp files or something where that data is stored. I am using Lubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by installing Nautilus. Now I use it as default file manager and have no problems stated above or any other at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the PCManFM re installation:

- Remove existing PCManFM.

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove pcmanfm
  ```
- Install PCManFM again.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
  ```
- After that reboot the system to see the changes.

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Comment: Tried that already, but problem wasn't solved. Nautilus was the only solution that worked. Thanks anyway.